# Null pointer in Repo while starting application

Tags: java, spring, jpa

My application was running smoothly and all of sudden after restart it shows such  error. I havent changed anything in UserRepo, Entity or OAuth Config

Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.ayush.mobilepos.repo.UserRepo.linkUserWithOffice(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long); Reason: null; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(QueryUtils.java:607) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DefaultQueryEnhancer.createCountQueryFor(DefaultQueryEnhancer.java:49) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.deriveCountQuery(StringQuery.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NativeJpaQuery.(NativeJpaQuery.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:51) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:169) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:253) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8-20230216.231902-43.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8-20230216.231505-41.jar:2.7.8-SNAPSHOT]
... 89 common frames omitted

I tried maven dependecies re importing and dropping databse

Comment: Can you format the log properly and provide the code in the class `com.ayush.mobilepos.repo.UserRepo.linkUserWithOffice` ?A possible thing might be that you got dicsonnected with your db earlier which wasn't a problem wth an already running application but is now.

Comment: This is the code: 
    @Modifying
    @Query(
            nativeQuery=true,
            value="update users set office_id = ?2 where id=?1"
    )
    void linkUserWithOffice(Long userId, Long officeId);

Comment: This may be related to a bug that was introduced in Spring Boot 2.7.9, see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34363. This will be fixed in 2.7.10.

Comment: Thanks @ChRyder. Upgrading Spring Boot to 2.7.13 resolved the issue.